# How to open an url from the browser with a parameter in ios

Tags: ios, openurl

I want to open an URL from the browser in ios. I know how to open an normal url.. but here I want to pass a parameter to the url.... This is what I used to open the url from the browser

`NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.iphonedevelopertips.com"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];`

Then how can I modify this according to pass a parameter

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here i pass the country name. you can pass anything what you want.

```
CountryName=@"India";   

NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx/GetCitiesByCountry?CountryName=%@",CountryName]];
```

do like this pass whatever you want pass like this.

Comment: This won't work. You need to use `stringWithFormat` to build the string.